# Transfer symbolic links between different filesystems

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems, copy, symlink

I am trying to emulate the advantages of a database on my filesystem for my music collection.

For example when I have a new album I would run a script which moves the album to another folder like this:

`/music/albums/The_Doors-1968-Waiting_For_The_Sun/`

I then want the script to make a symbolic link (symlink) based on the year:

`/music/links/by_year/1968/The_Doors-1968-Waiting_For_The_Sun`

The benefit of this is, that I can create multiple folders with symlink-categories and browse them very fast (genre/year/…).

My question is now: **Can the symlinks be copied from one file system to another?** I am currently on a Mac but want to have a system which can easily be transfered to a NTFS harddisc (or another future filesystem). I would like this system to be future-save and program- and platform independent. Any thoughts about this approach are very welcome, too!

Comment: I did some research and it seems like all Unix-based operation systems can handle the same soft- and hardlinks. Windows uses another system for that, so transferring symlinks between Unix-based systems and Windows needs extra software.